# Something about pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to output the number of occurrences of each element in a list, so, I use this:

```py
c1 = a.value_counts()
print(c1)
```

Which results in:

> ```
> 深圳市腾讯计算机系统有限公司    2658
> 字节跳动               997
> 阿里巴巴集团             647
> 南京学无涯文化发展有限公司      338
> 深圳市乐易网络股份有限公司      293
>                   ... 
> 杭州普略生物科技有限公司         1
> 深圳市乐活电子商务有限公司       1
> 北京大数医达科技有限公司         1
> 沈阳康泰电子科技股份有限公司     1
> 苏州麦子文化传媒有限公司         1
> ```

But, when I use

```py
a.value_counts().to_csv(outputpath1,index=False)
```

I can only see the numbers in the CSV file, not the names.
I want to know why, and, how can I output names and numbers together?

Comment: don't pass `index=False` ?

Comment: yes,I'm used to converting to CSV files without index

Comment: The output of value_counts is a pd.Series with the values you are counting in the index, and the counts as the data for the pd.Series.   Try: `a.value_counts().reset_index().to_csv(outputpath1, index=False)`